# Using React, how can sibling components best share a state? Should there even be a way to traverse DOM tree...?

Tags: reactjs

How can sibling components best share a state in React? Take for example a component that has a series of checkboxes as children: If one is clicked by the user, how can the others be unchecked? (This is just an example to illustrate the problem, ignoring the fact that radio buttons can solve this particular issue.)

```
<Form>
  <Checkbox />
  <Checkbox checked />
  <Checkbox />
</Form>

function Form() {
  // State and/or context business here maybe?

  return <form>{children}</form>
}

function Checkbox({checked}) {
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    // check this and uncheck all siblings
  }

  return <input type="checkbox" checked onClick={handleClick} />
}
```

A similar but common use example: Click a box element; Change className to "on"; Change sibling element classNames to "off";

In jQuery, there is a similar way to access siblings through the Tree Traversal API. Something along these lines:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
});
```

I'm still new to React and not sure if this is a desired functionality.

Comment: define your own state using `useState` at the parent level instead of reaching into the checkbox for its state

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-hill-eru16?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of what i think you are trying to do.

Comment: @Yousaf This example helps a lot  Map the child components, assign index prop to each one, use index as the state value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to having child components share a state is to define the state in the common ancestor, then map the children, assigning an index to each one, using the index as the state value. The following example solution is based on an example from @Yousaf and @Nick Roth's solution to "lift state" to the common ancestor component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Checkbox />
      <Checkbox checked />
      <Checkbox />
    </Form>
  );
}

function Form({ children }) {
  // find the checked component to assign initial state
  let initChecked;
  React.Children.forEach(children, (child, index) => {
      if (child.props.checked) {
          initChecked = index;
      }
  });

  // Lift state to the common ancestor component of the checkboxes
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(initChecked);
  
  // Map children, assigning index and state
  return <form>{React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    if (isChild(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        index,
        setChecked,
        checked: checked === index,
      });
    }

    return child;
  })}</form>;
}

function Checkbox({ index, checked, setChecked }) {
  return <input type="checkbox" checked onClick={() => setChecked(index)} />
}

function isChild(component) {
  // Some Mechanism to check if the component is a wanted <Checkbox /> component
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This answer deserves definitely some cleanup. Ignoring some else's answer and reusing theirs for a sub-ideal solution while accepting only your's isn't fair for the people who took the time and effort to help you out. And no... that's not the answer, it's one way to do it. The answer and best way to do it is @Nick Roth's answer.

Comment: This answer provides a workable solution to the issue that one answer proposed. There was also a suggested example, but where that example maps known concrete children components, the above answer illustrates how ambiguous children components can share a state. I credited those people in my answer, and would like to thank them again for taking the time to help clarify a complex issue to someone like me who is still new to React. Thanks again, Yousaf and Nick.

Comment: Okay. Fair enough. A workable solution isn't necessarily a good solution. Yours e.g. isn't accounting for nesting (wrapping your checkbox with a label e.g.) and all checkboxes are checked initially when I run your example. `isChild` isn't specified in your question nor the initial filtering of immediate children which is checked. Hence the need to clean it up. Index is one option though and can be seen as A particular solution. Don't take it personal I was just code-reviewing, kinda. In React you can 100% find an even easier solution though. Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution for this in React is to "lift state". Essentially if there is shared state between components, find the common ancestor and move the state there. React has some of their own docs on it as well https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

So in your example, the `Form` component is where the checked state of the checkboxes should live. `Form` is the one that would know when other checkboxes get clicked and can coordinate the updates as required.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. This helps to understand where state should be defined. However, I'm still unsure about state management: If state is defined in `Form`, what's the best way for child components (`Checkbox` in the example) to manage state that's been lifted out to the parent?